# PyKCS11 installation

Tags: python, macos

I want to install and use PyKCS11 to my mac (via terminal). I want to use python3 for the whole process. I downloaded it from here: https://bitbucket.org/PyKCS11/pykcs11.

I have python3 installed at /usr/local/lib. I downloaded the folder, ran make build, and everything was ok. When i run make install i get the following:

```
python3 setup.py install --prefix=/usr/local --root=/
running install
running build
running build_py
running build_ext
running install_lib
running install_egg_info
Removing /usr/local/lib/python3.4/site-packages/PyKCS11-1.3.2-py3.4.egg-info
Writing /usr/local/lib/python3.4/site-packages/PyKCS11-1.3.2-py3.4.egg-info
```

(*Removing... is from the previous time i executed the command)

After that, i open python3 and execute `import PyKCS11`
and i get the following error:

```
>>> import PyKCS11
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/Dkostas/Desktop/tools/PyKCS11/PyKCS11/LowLevel.py", line 18, in swig_import_helper
    fp, pathname, description = imp.find_module('_LowLevel', [dirname(__file__)])
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.4/lib/python3.4/imp.py", line 297, in find_module
    raise ImportError(_ERR_MSG.format(name), name=name)
ImportError: No module named '_LowLevel'

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/Users/Dkostas/Desktop/tools/PyKCS11/PyKCS11/__init__.py", line 20, in <module>
    import PyKCS11.LowLevel
  File "/Users/Dkostas/Desktop/tools/PyKCS11/PyKCS11/LowLevel.py", line 28, in <module>
    _LowLevel = swig_import_helper()
  File "/Users/Dkostas/Desktop/tools/PyKCS11/PyKCS11/LowLevel.py", line 20, in swig_import_helper
    import _LowLevel
ImportError: No module named '_LowLevel'
```

Could it be a problem that python3 cannot use swig?

Python2 is installed at a different location (/usr/lib/python2.7) 

I used Homebrew to install python.

Any ideas appreciated.
Thanks in advance!

Comment: why not use `pip` to install?

Answer (score 0):

you need to come out from PyKCS11 directory and for more info check the below link
https://github.com/LudovicRousseau/PyKCS11/issues/70